# How to avoid [RST] packets from the server?

Tags: tcp, wireshark, winsock

My client app is sending `http` req to routers `webserver`. The server responds with the intended data but the wireshark traffic shows that after every transaction, The server is sending `[RST,ACK]` & `[RST]` `tcp` packets which i believe is not a good idea.

My client creates (and close) new `socket` for every `http` transaction. But from `[RST]` it seems like my client is sending packet on the server's closed `socket`. In my `recv` function, the server response is "**An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host**"

```
do{
    ret_err = recv(MySocket, recv_buffer, RECV_BUFF_LENGTH, 0);
    if (ret_err == SOCKET_ERROR){
        break;    /* Ignoring errors [server response : "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" */
    }
} while(ret_err != 0); 
HANDLE_WINSOC_ERR(shutdown(MySocket, SD_RECEIVE));
closesocket(MySocket);
```

Packet 9 (see below image) is `http` reply msg from the `server` which contains `FIN` flag; which could mean that i should respond with `[FIN,ACK]` not just `[ACK]` as seen in the below diagram [my client app responded with only `ACK` i.e. at Packet 10].

[image]

As i am working on application layer, is their a mechanism to transmit `FIN` signal after `recv` ?

My client app is using `Winsoc`.

Comment: My guess is that your client is actually wrong, for example by sending more data after the HTTP request or sending a slightly malformed request. It might also be that the server is wrong by not fully reading the HTTP request before closing. Unfortunately you don't provide the necessary part of your client and server so this is just speculation. As for transmitting FIN after `recv`: a socket close or shutdown will do this. But it is unlikely that this fixes the RST.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: You are right. I was sending more data to the server. [RST] disappeared now. Thank you